# WP Logs me out after updating anything on dashboard

Tags: admin, redirect, dashboard, cookies, logout

Not sure what is going on here but my live site kicks the admin out every time they change something in the dasboard. For instance when an admin updates a page the url looks like `http://mysite.com//wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D9%26action%3Dedit%26message%3D1&reauth=1` on the live site and like `http://mysite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=11&action=edit&message=1` on the test server. This is with all plugins disabled. I have no idea what is causing this. Can anyone gimme a hand?

Comment: I'd begin by checking the 'siteurl' and 'home' fields in the wp_options table in the database, maybe something's wrong there. Have you been editing your functions.php file and put some buggy code there perhaps?

Comment: I have been making all sorts of functions in functions.php but the thing is that my dev site is fine and my live site is not and they share the same code. Also siteurl and home do have the same value.

Comment: So both the code and the database (especially the wp_options table) are the same on both sites? And everything is acting normal on the live site in wp-admin until you try to save a post or page? Have you tried reinstalling WP?

Comment: Do you have any cookie blocking or ad blocking software on your browser?

Comment: @RichardB Yes and no I have not tried reinstalling WP?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Im using the same browser to access the live site and the dev site and no I dont have any blocking software installed.

Comment: Cookie setting/blocking settings can be site specific. I sometimes have to whitelist sites I work on. :)

Comment: Do you have any SSL-related option enabled in wp-config?

Comment: Failure of migrating databases can affect site behaviour in the strangest of ways, something might be corrupt in there. It only takes a few minutes to reinstall WP (download and replace all WP-files except wp-content). After that I'd probably compare .htaccess and webserver/PHP conf between dev and live site.

Comment: @RichardB Ill probably give that a try